# Import WCF service client settings from app.config into code structure

Tags: c#, vb.net, web-services, wcf

I have written a hello world WCF web service. My App.config file for the client application that consumes the service is below. I want all of this data to be set within the client application's code. How can I do this? I want to write a class that encapsulates all of the properties and methods that I need to set in my code. I've captured almost all of the Endpoint and Binding properties but I'm having some difficulties with the Contract settings. I'd be interested if anyone has been able to get this to work without a config file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
</startup>

<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IHelloWorldService" allowCookies="true"
             maxReceivedMessageSize="20000000" maxBufferSize="20000000"                         maxBufferPoolSize="20000000">
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="32"
                maxArrayLength="200000000"
                maxStringContentLength="200000000"/>
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>

 <endpoint address="http://localhost/HelloWorldService.svc"
      binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IHelloWorldService"
      contract="HelloWordServiceReference.IHelloWorldService"
      name="BasicHttpBinding_IHelloWorldService" />

</client>
</system.serviceModel>

</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you like to add all the client side properties, classes of your service, wcf service comes up with something service proxy. So what happens when you create a wcf service (self hosted or web server), and add the service reference via url visual studio will automatically generate the proxy class which will contain everything to needed to consume web service from your client end. But if you would like to manually create the client proxy you can follow this url [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734691(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734691%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: I'm not talking about creating a proxy class. The proxy class doesn't contain everything I need to consume my web service. I also need to have the above app.config file in the app path of the client application's executable. I want to do away with this file and incorporate all of the settings into my client application's source code.

Comment: if you add your service reference via visual studio all these app.config will be added to your client app.config too

Comment: I want to not have to deploy an App.config file at all. I want to examine the App.config file that Visual Studio creates and embed these settings into my VB.NET or C# code.